# How to reset css fonts cache

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I've changed my fonts in the server, but the browser get the old version of the css file where fonts are writed, how to reset the cache?, i've tried to delete browser cache and delete the old file css, but they still are getting the old cs, i've tried to reload the server, how to fix that?

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed this happen only in Firefox, which is very annoying, however, if this is the same situation as you here, refresh with SHIFT + CMD + R (if you're on a mac, I presume the windows alternative is CTRL + SHIFT + R)

That'll clear your cache for that page too + SHOULD show your fonts :)

Comment: This may work fine for you/the developer, but it is not a good solution for users who have the old css and fonts loaded.

Comment: Please forgive this answer was written in 2013 and the tech has changed since then, 6 years later

Comment: In Firefox the usual methods for reloading the page do not refresh the font cache. One method that may work is `History > Delete recent history - Everything`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002546/clear-firefox-font-cache).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your browser isn't displaying local fonts — I spent almost one hour trying to figure out how to clear the font cache in Firefox, while the issue had nothing to do with that.

Check your webserver logs : are font files downloaded ?  If not, then it's likely you're using local fonts.

Consider this real case scenario :

```
@font-face{
    font-family: SuperFont;
    src: url('../fonts/Superfont.ttf'),
}
```

I copypasted this code from somewhere, removing part of the `src` definition, **not noticing the ending comma** which made this line invalid CSS.  Therefore the font was not downloaded.

However, since I had Superfont already installed locally, it *seemed* to work because the browser recognized the `font-family`.  Well, until I decided to change the font file, but keeping the `font-family` definition to spare further modifications of the CSS file…

Morality : when testing fonts, use an unambiguous custom `font-family` name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing the page in a different browser to ensure the old font isn't still being added to the page?

If you're still using the same CSS file, you can navigate to the CSS file and do a hard refresh on that Ctrl+F5.

Also, I've found that closing the page completely before clearing your cache can help too!

Answer (score 0):

Just add version for url:

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: FontName;
    src: url('fonts/FontName.woff2?v=2.0') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/FontName.eot?#iefix&v=2.0') format('eot');
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Do a : Ctrl + F5 on your browser