# How to clear browser font cache

Tags: firefox, browser, fonts, font-face, chromium

I'd like to "remove" some fonts added using the CSS property `@font-face` in my browser (firefox or chromium).

I know which font because I see it with the Dev Tools' Inspector and I assume it's in the font cache because it's not loaded (nothing in the Dev Tools' Network tab).

The goal is to see what are the fonts files requested by a library, but as soon as the fonts are already installed, I'm not able to see them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset css fonts cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894941/how-to-reset-css-fonts-cache). It seems a reload already refreshes the font cache, but you may be trying to clear the font cache for wrong reasons, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40311591/812102).