# Clear firefox font cache

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

> Note: this is not a duplicate of
> [How to reset css fonts cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894941/how-to-reset-css-fonts-cache) See the bottom of my question

## TL;DR

I'm searching for a reliable way of purging the font cache of Firefox as neither `CTRL`+`F5` nor `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`R` seems to work.

## My Problem

I'm using a custom font (via css) on my server:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MySymbols;
    src: url(../fonts/MySymbols.woff);
}
```

I recently added another symbol to the font (Unicode: 21C5 / ⇅).

### Under Chrome

It should look like the two arrows in this picture. The screenshot is from Chrome, which displays it correctly:

[image: screenshot chrome]

The two "u"s after that are there to prove that I'm loading the correct font. The left one uses MySymbols as font-family and the right one uses a standard font.

### Under Firefox

Now with Firefox it looks like this:

[image: screenshot firefox]

It looks like Firefox still uses the old font face. The left "u" is displayed correctly, but for the arrows Firefox uses a standard font as fallback.

When I change `src: url(../fonts/MySymbols.woff);` to `src: url(../fonts/MySymbols_something.woff);` and rename the font file on the server accordingly Firefox correctly displays the following:

[image: screenshot firefox new]

When I change back both names Firefox displays the aforementioned picture with the wrong arrows again, which is very frustrating.

## What I tried to solve the problem on my own

I'm aware of the following thread: [How to reset css fonts cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894941/how-to-reset-css-fonts-cache)
And I worked through all of the solutions. None of them worked.
In particular I checked the following things:

- I tried pressing `CTRL`+`F5`
- I tried pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`R` (which used to work some time ago)
- I restarted firefox, closed the tab and opened it again
- The font isn't found anywhere in my system directories. I checked that with `sudo updatedb; locate MySymbols.woff`, I haven't installed the font myself and I guess the name is not very common
- The CSS is correct and works perfectly in Chrome

What could be going on and what other things are there left to try?

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the OP has tried the solutions in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

History > Clear Recent History > Ensure 'everything' is selected at the top, together with 'cache' and 'offline website data'

Comment: Yep that worked. Somehow I've overlooked that method.

Comment: I had a similar problem using font awesome a while back, not sure whether or not the font is stored in the 'offline website data' or not.