# Firefox doesn't recognize font anymore after update

Tags: css, vue.js, firefox, vuejs3

I develop a VueJS app, with custom fonts loaded like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Caviar Dreams';
  src: local('Caviar Dreams'), url(~@/assets/fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

It has always worked, but I upgraded my development computer from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, and my Firefox version and since then it doesn't work anymore. The strange part is that it still works on Chrome (I upgraded Chrome too, though).

I tried to see if there was some cache to delete, up to no avail (I tried the solution described here: [Clear firefox font cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002546/clear-firefox-font-cache)).

I tried to remove the `local` part in my css, and it works, so I suppose the problem comes from the local fonts. I looked here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1330946 , no solution work. What is even stranger is that I have local fonts working perfectly and some others no.

I want to be able to use local fonts because I don't want the user to download the fonts everytime (I think about the planet!).

How can I make my custom fonts work again on Firefox? What happened here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to see if the font is loaded or if there is some error in the firefox console?

I have always used relative paths and I have never experienced this problem

Here an example of a vue project of mine

```
/* bitter-regular - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bitter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Bitter Regular'), local('Bitter-Regular'),
    url('../fonts/bitter/bitter-v12-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
    url('../fonts/bitter/bitter-v12-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}
```

Comment: I have no error in the console but the font is not loaded (when I hover the font name in the inspector it doesn't display it correctly).

Comment: And in the network tab the font is loaded? Be sure to do a complete refresh (CTRL+SHIFT+R)

Comment: I edited my question, it indeed comes from the local fonts.

Comment: Can you use the relative path as a test and see what happens?

Comment: Consider that fonts are not downloaded every time, but are saved in the browser cache, whether you put them on your server or use cdn

Comment: There is no problem with the 'url' part, whether the path is relative or not, the problem comes from some local files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247076/discussion-between-johnnyglamour-and-djcaesar9114).